# Programming Transition Loses Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm having an issue with my `main.storyboard` file.  I changed the settings of my app so that the start screen is the main.storyboard file, rather than `LaunchScreen.xib`.  The initial `ViewController` is the `NavigationController`, and the second is my `SplashScreeViewController`.  (I created my own splash screen in the storyboard so that I could change it with additional code.)  I use a line of code in my splash screen to later transition to the second view controller.  Here it is:

```
var controller:UIViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Second") as! ViewController
controller.modalTransitionStyle = .CrossDissolve
self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

For some reason, when I transition to that second `ViewController`, the navigation bar that should be at the top (of the second `ViewController`) isn't there, opposite of what was shown in the `main.storyboard` file.  I tried to add an invisible, disabled button to the splash screen as to add a connection between the two view controllers, and therefore adding a navigation bar to the second, but when the splash transitions on its own, no navigation bar appears on the second.

**Is there a way I could have a navigation bar on my second view controller without dragging one in, nor programming it in?  I would like to use the one Xcode provides when you create a new connection between controllers.**

Thanks in advance to all who reply.

*(I apologize for the lack of pictures to help describe my problem.  I don't have enough 'reputation' to do so.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to embed your `Second` view controller on a Navigation Controller, and then instantiate that navigation controller instead.

Answer (score -1):

This might solve the problem - It looks like you are presenting a modal view controller when you probably want to be pushing your view controller from your initial navigation controller with `pushViewController`